# Get application that is using a given file

Tags: c#, io, file-permissions

How can I get in C# the application that is using a given file ?

To be more precise, if the app I am developing wants to overwrite a file that is being used by another application, I would like to display an error message such as : "Close application XXX before overwriting file YYY".

Comment: Thanks Tim for giving the link to duplicated question